# Should I create a GitHub App or GitHub OAuth App?

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, github-app, github-oauth

I am trying to create a website that will allow users to authorize their GitHub account and it will then allow the user to click a `create` button. Which automatically creates a new repo with some files. Now I am confused about should I make a GitHub app or OAuth app for the same.
I have looked into the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/differences-between-github-apps-and-oauth-apps) but still confused..
I will host the website and this will allow any random user with an GitHub account.. What will be the best choice?

Answer (score 5):

From Github [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps):

> GitHub Apps are the officially recommended way to integrate with
> GitHub because they offer much more granular permissions to access
> data, but GitHub supports both OAuth Apps and GitHub Apps.

They are also providing a [simple flow chart](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps#determining-which-integration-to-build) that can make your decision easier.

Bottom line - unless you need an access to everything, you should use **GitHub App**